# Yii generate xml and show in html formatted

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

I need to generate sitemap for one of my Yii website.
There is only 3 controller that needs to show in xml,

Productscontroll,Blogscontroll,Categorycontroll,

what is a best way to generate exml and show in html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I integrated Zend 2.0 Feed into Yii and outputted my data as an XML Sitemap.

I used http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/505/integrating-zf2-into-yii-use-case-demonstrated/ as a base to work with incorporating Zend 2 properly and http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/index.html#zend-feed as to how to use the Feed Class to output the desired XML